# Change sysctl parameters for all interfaces

Tags: systemd, sysctl

How can i change a parameter for all interfaces in systemd ?

For example:

```
sysctl -w "net.ipv4.conf.eth0.rp_filter=0"
sysctl -w "net.ipv4.conf.eth1.rp_filter=0"
```

How can change it for all interfaces ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `all` and `default`:

```
# sysctl -w "net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=0"
# sysctl -w "net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter=0"
```

This is explained in the [Kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt):

```
conf/default/*:    Change the interface-specific default settings.
conf/all/*:        Change all the interface-specific settings.
```

However note that putting a new value in `all` doesn't change the value you read from
the interface, but it only gets computed and used internally. See this [email](http://marc.info/?l=linux-kernel&m=123606366021995&w=2) for more details.

Comment: no, it doesn't work

Comment: what doesn't work?

Comment: The value for eth0, eth1 and other interfaces doesn't change

Comment: That's "normal", I've updated my answer.

Comment: So if i modify those parameters, new interfaces will habe the new values ?

Comment: If you modify `default`, new interfaces will get them as default value. If you modify `all`, the actual value will be computed using the value defined by `all` and the one in the interface settings.